# I want to update a button's color when a condition is verified in swift

Tags: swift

I want to update a button's color when a condition is verified in swift. I don't how to do it as UIKit doesn't have an update function like SpriteKit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Call this code within the condition that you say where the button is accessible.

```
button.backgroundColor = .red
```